# Как правильно будет написать?

Tags: орфография

Она была юна, или она была юнна (в смысле молода)?

Answer (score 3):

> Она была юна, или она была юнна?

Правильно с одним "н": ***юна.***

См. [**словарь:**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%8E%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Юный – словарное прилагательное с одной буквой Н, в краткой форме также сохраняется одна буква Н: юн/ый – юн/а (= молода).

**Но откуда возьмутся две буквы НН?**

Возможно, это попытка выбора Н/НН  по образцу причастий и отпричастных прилагательных: дети **воспитаны** (кем?) родителями (причастие, одна буква Н) - они (каковы?) умны и **воспитанны** (прилагательное, две буквы НН).

Comment: Да какие там причастия... Было такое популярное слово "юннат" - от него ноги и растут.

Comment: Если это Юнна Мориц, она ещё пока есть. Но не совсем юна.